# JEST testing on redux is not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, jsx, enzyme

I have a code in redux which i exported as

```jsx
 export default connect(mapStateToLinkProps, mapDispatchToLinkProps)(Link);
```

And in jest test case i have written to test this exported component

```jsx
//imported the above component as Link
describe('Dashboard component testing', () => {
  test('1. Must be an Instance of CreateAssest', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<FilterLink />);
    const inst = wrapper.instance();
    expect(inst).toBeInstanceOf(Link);
  });
});
```

For this i'm getting error

> Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or
>   props of "Connect(Link)". Either wrap the root component in a
>   , or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(Link)".

When not using redux and exporting only as react component the test cases were working.Now in redux some store issue is coming.please can anyone guide a little in this issue what's happening

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your component in Provider in order to be able to use store, like so:

```jsx
import { Provider, connect } from "react-redux";
let store = createStore(reducer, defaultStoreItems); 
<Provider store={store}>  
  <App />    
</Provider>
```